# How to display a word cloud in ionic utilizing WordCloud NPM?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, word-cloud

I already did the @types installation and the word cloud package installation. Yet, I'm still getting errors and unable to display the word cloud.

typescript and html code below:

```js
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

    import { WordCloud } from 'wordcloud';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {

      list = [['foo', 12], ['bar', 6]];

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      }

      WordCloud(document.getElementById('my_canvas'), { list: list } );
}
```

```html
    <ion-header>
      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
          Ionic Blank
        </ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content padding>
      <canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
    </ion-content>
```

I'm utilizing this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordcloud

Comment: Errors I'm getting:


Typescript Error
';' expected.
src/pages/home/home.ts
 WordCloud.WordCloud(document.getElementById('my_canvas'), { list: list } );
  
Typescript Error
',' expected.
src/pages/home/home.ts
 WordCloud.WordCloud(document.getElementById('my_canvas'), { list: list } );

Comment: Typescript Error
'=' expected.
src/pages/home/home.ts
 WordCloud.WordCloud(document.getElementById('my_canvas'), { list: list } );

Comment: Typescript Error
File '/Users/username/Documents/Ionic App/testApp/node_modules/@types/wordcloud/index.d.ts' is not a module.
src/pages/home/home.ts
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WordCloud } from 'wordcloud';
Typescript Error
Duplicate identifier 'WordCloud'.
src/pages/home/home.ts
 WordCloud.WordCloud(document.getElementById('my_canvas'), { list: list } );

Comment: Typescript Error
Duplicate identifier 'WordCloud'.
src/pages/home/home.ts
 WordCloud.WordCloud(document.getElementById('my_canvas'), { list: list } );
  
Typescript Error
Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.
src/pages/home/home.ts
 WordCloud.WordCloud(document.getElementById('my_canvas'), { list: list } );

Comment: Typescript Error
A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
src/pages/home/home.ts
 WordCloud.WordCloud(document.getElementById('my_canvas'), { list: list } );